# Basis for vector space $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is whether my solution to the following problem is valid. The problem is from Artin's Algebra, chapter 3:

Let $(X_1,\cdots,X_m)$ and $(Y_1,\cdots,Y_n)$ be bases for $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, respectively. Do the $mn$ matrices $X_iY_j^T$ form a basis for the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ of all $m\times n$ matrices?

I know the answer is yes, but for the past few hours I've been struggling with how to give a generalized proof. I feel like I may have made it harder than it should be. Here is what I've come up with after scouring the chapter and other resources. Is this valid?

Take $E=\{e_1,\cdots,e_m\}$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $F=\{f_1,\cdots,f_n\}$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then for bases $(X_1,\cdots,X_m)$ and $(Y_1,\cdots,Y_n)$, there exist basechange matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $Pe_i=X_i$ for $1\leq i \leq m$ and $Qf_j=Y_j$ for $1\leq j \leq n$. Then for any matrix $M\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, we know $$\Sigma c_{ij}e_if_j^T=P^{-1}M(Q^{-1})^T$$ since $\{e_if_j^T\}$ is clearly a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Then $$P(\Sigma c_{ij}e_if_j^T)Q^T=PP^{-1}M(Q^{-1})^TQ^T=M \\ \implies \Sigma c_{ij}X_iY_j^T=M.$$
This shows that $\{X_iY_j^T\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. We also know that the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ has $mn$ elements, so that the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is $mn$. So we have a set $\{X_iY_j^T\}$ of $mn$ elements that span $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, which has dimension $mn$. Then it must be the case that the elements of $\{X_iY_j^T\}$ are independent. Thus, $\{X_iY_j^T\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

Comment: For reference, the same exercise was asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/250641 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/901210.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

Suppose $\sum_i \sum_j \alpha_{ij} x_i y_j^T = 0$.

Choose $v$, then look at $\sum_i \sum_j \alpha_{ij} x_i y_j^Tv = \sum_i (\sum_j \alpha_{ij} y_j^Tv) x_i = 0$.

Since the $x_i$ are li., we have
$\sum_j \alpha_{ij} y_j^Tv = (\sum_j \alpha_{ij} y_j^T)v = 0$ for all $i$.

Since this is true for all $v$, we have $\sum_j \alpha_{ij} y_j^T = 0$ for all $i$. Since the $y_j$ are li., we have $\alpha_{ij} = 0$ for all $i,j$.